# REST's 'resource communication mechanisms' and 'on-the-fly' improvement of a client's knowledge of them

Tags: rest

I'm trying to come to terms with REST, as defined by Roy Fielding.  Recently I've been trying to wrap my mind around:

http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven

The concept I'm interested in is in this quote:

> The transitions may be determined (or limited by) the client’s knowledge of media types and resource communication mechanisms, both of which may be improved on-the-fly (e.g., code-on-demand).

Specifically, what is knowledge of "resource communication mechanisms", how is that knowledge described in documentation/specs and realised in an implemntation?
Then, how best to improve that knowledge 'on-the-fly'?
I think I understand addressing 'the client's knowledge of media types'.

I have some guesses (PUT,GET, etc.) but would appreciate any suggestions, examples or pointers to RESTful API's that explicitly adress the issues in that quote.  If it helps I'm thinking about these issues in the context of HTTP+JSON, I appreciate REST isn't limited to HTTP+*.

The Sun Cloud API has previously been cited as good RESTful design, I couldn't see where or how it addressed these specific issues - maybe a case of not seeing the wood for the trees?

Clarification:

What puzzles me is if PUT,GET,etc. are these mechanisms, this suggests a client knows which to apply to specific hyperlinks within some <media-type>, and this seems  fragile, and might suggest hypertext-links map (directly) to resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Resource Communication Mechanisms

By "resource communication mechanisms", I believe Roy is referring to HTTP requests and HTTP verbs.  He is just saying it without being specify to HTTP because REST is not dependent on HTTP.  I would say that for 99.99% of all REST services, the resource communication mechanism is documented in [RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html).

The Sun Cloud API meets these requirements because all a client needs to understand to use the API is how to do HTTP requests and the semantics of the returned media types.  For example if a client does not understand what is contained in a document of type `application/vnd.com.sun.cloud.Cloud+json` then it will not be able to use the API.

This is in contrast with services like [OData](http://www.odata.org/) and [SData](http://sdata.sage.com/index.html) that do not define new media-types, but assume a client knows how to extract domain data out of an Atom feed and expects the client to construct URLs based on a set of rules that define the URI space.  This is in direct violation of Roy's recommendations.

#### Improved on the fly

To be honest, I can only guess at what Roy is alluding to here.  I could imagine a scenario where downloaded javascript could be used to construct an url based on user input. This could prevent the server from having to explicitly generate an url for each element in a list.

Also, certain valid transitions could be enabled or disabled on the fly based on user input. Consider the case where you do not want to enable a submit button until the user has entered all the required fields.  The retrieved document contains the link to allow the transition, but the downloaded code controls when and if the user can select the link.

Downloaded code could also, be used to dynamically change the verb on a link.  If you wish to edit a resource, it could do a GET, if you want to delete that resource, you do a DELETE.  This would allow the representation to only contain a single link but be able to perform multiple operations.

Comment: Thanks, that was largely my understanding.  I thought base knowledge and 'on-the-fly' updating could be communicated as uri field name or link data, eg get_uri or link id/name.  On-the-fly updates are via mediatype contents,e.g., a delete_uri field, or link element with 'delete' name/id.  I don't see this happening, instead often/always the verb-uri relation is communicated 'out-of-band', e.g. the Sun Cloud API spec doc's Resource table contents.  Roy's 4th point pretty much describes the Sun Cloud API... and rules it out as RESTful, and not just on this RCM point?

Comment: It is not really necessary to define a specific link for deleting a resource because if you know the URI of the resource then the HTTP rules say that issuing the DELETE verb to the URI will cause the resource to be deleted.  A client can always use OPTIONS to determine the allowed verbs on a URI.  I don't see the fact that the documentation also provides this information as a problem.  It is perfectly valid to communicate specific behaviour in relation to particular media-types.  The message is still self-describing because the content-type tells the client what rules to follow.

Comment: Nice point on the use of OPTIONS in communicating changes on-the-fly.  Though I like it alot, I'm still a little reserved on the RESTfulness of the Sun Cloud API, maybe it's the 'Resource heirachy/naming' orientation of the docs that has me off balance - I'd expected to see more emphasis on media-types, server instructions to "clients on how to construct appropriate URIs", and media-type processing rules.  Thanks for sharing your insights.

Comment: It is pretty sad that the Sun REST API is actually one of the best examples of REST documentation out there.  I really hope that someone else produces a decent API in the near future that we can point to as a good example.  There is certainly no problem find bad ones!